# Accessing HTML controls inside iFrame

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How do you access html controls inside an iframe from javascript in CRM?

I have:

```js
 var height = document.getElementById("IFRAME_TransactionProduct_RA").contentWindow.document.getElementById("txt").value;
```

but that results in "Error on page" and the content is not loaded.

The element I want to access is an html input with id of 'txt':

```xml
 <input id="txt" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: You want access from Iframe to a control inside of CRM Form or the controls inside of the same IFrame?

Comment: inside the iframe aspx page (it's a client side control though)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example how you copy a value from a CRM field to a control in an embedded HTML control in an IFRAME. I'm assuming the names of the web resource and the field. You'll have to adapt those. You also might throw in a *try-catch* in case CRM throws in en exception (got the joke?) and please mind that I'm typing the code on my phone so there **might** be a typo somewhere (auto-correction, yey).

```javascript
var source = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("oneCoolField")
var information = source.getValue();

var customHtml = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("WebResource_EmbeddedHtmlContent");
var destination = customHtml.getObject().contentWindow.document;
if(destination) {
  var customControl = destination.getElementById("elementToAccess");
  if(customControl) {
    customControl.value = information;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

This gets you to the web resource.

```javascript
var customHtml = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("WebResource_EmbeddedHtmlContent");
```

This gets you to the DOM of the IFRAME.

```javascript
var destination = customHtml.getObject().contentWindow.document;
```

This gets you to the control on the custom page.

```javascript
var customControl = destination.getElementById("elementToAccess");
```

This gets you the contents of the control.

```javascript
var contents = customControl.innerHTML;
```

Which part fails on your computer?

Comment: I guess I need to clarify the question. I'm trying to access a client side control inside the iframe page (aspx file) from a javascript web resource in CRM (which executes on page load event).

Comment: can you just load the JS into the IFrame?

Comment: Well, what I've usually do is to load in a web resource that is HTML containing the stuff to display. In it's *head* tag, I can link to a script. Other method is to have a script as a web resource and call it from a fired event handler.

Answer (score 1):

**With jQuery:**

```
$(Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('IFRAME_TransactionProduct_RA').getObject()).contents().find('#txt').val();
```

**Pure JS:**

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('IFRAME_TransactionProduct_RA').getObject().contentWindow.document.getElementById('txt').value;
```

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_getObject*